# 'Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported' - Azure Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, deployment, csproj

I'm getting a `'Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported'` error when deploying to Azure.

Here's the deployment log

```
    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
  Filanthropy.Model -> D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Model\bin\Release\Filanthropy.Model.dll
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Runtime.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Reflection.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Reflection.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.IO.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.IO.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.4.3.0-preview1-24530-04\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Core\Filanthropy.Core.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Filanthropy.Web\Filanthropy.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d3fe5a038ffaf0";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\58.51019.2480\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

i've been through the relevant csproj file, and can confirm that there are no duplicates in it.  This doesm't happen on my local machine, only when deploying to azure.

Comment: I created an ASP.NET MVC website and referenced the libs mentioned in the above deployment log. And I could successfully deploy my app to Azure Web App from my local Git repository. Have you tried to deploy your project directly to your Azure web app?